# Scaling 3D objects to same size and placing them at exactly 1m away from iphone/ipad camera using Arkit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, arscnview

[image]I need to scale a set of 3D objects to same size and place them at a distance of 1m from the iPad. I am having an transparent image on the screen just above the ARSCNView and I am trying to overlap the 3d object exactly in behind the transparent image and size should also match. Any link OR suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you know the size of your assets already (i.e if you created the models yourself) then you can change the `.scale` property on the root `SCNNode` for each object so that the resulting sizes are all the same.

i.e:

```
node.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.1, 0.2, 0.8)
```

If you have one object with size n1 = (1, 2, 1) (in metres) and another of size n2 = (2, 2, 2) then you can scale the first by `node.scale(2.0, 1.0, 2.0)` - now both objects will be the same size, however obviously the first will be distorted as you've changed its dimensions.

To place nodes at a distance of 1m from the origin you use:

```
node.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -1)  // x = 0, y = 0, z = -1
```

I'm unsure quite what you're talking about when you mention the transparent overlay - but if you explain this a bit further then myself or someone else can help you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of the dimensions of the objects that I am using and can place the object at any coordinate with respect to the origin. I am having an issue with placing an object at fixed distance from the device camera. In sample screen attached with the question which is little similar to the actual one, I am trying to place a 3D glasses which will overlap the dotted glass boundary always. Hope this clarifies my problem.

Comment: What sort of problem are you exactly having when you say "placing an object at fixed distance from the device camera". Do they not remain fixed? Using the `node.position` property should do exactly what you want. Then just scale the objects so they fit in the glasses frame. Do you mean that you want the objects to move as you move the camera around?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What I mean is when I try to keep the object 1m away from the camera using code - var translation=matrix_identity_float4x4;translation.columns.3.z= -1 object.simdTransform=matrix_multiply((self.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform)!, translation) . This doesn't work always. Sometimes if I have any plane/wall at a distance 2m from the camera, I see that object is placed at 1m from both camera and plane. If I have vertical plane/wall at distance of 6m, object is is rendered at a random distance. Please guide me to solve this. You can refer the attached image above.